# integral inequality having function and its derivatives

Tags: inequality

> Let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a derivable function , with a continuous derivative $g'$ on $[0,1],$ If $g(0.5)=0,$ Then prove that $\displaystyle \bigg(\int^{1}_{0}g(x)dx\bigg)^2\leq \frac{1}{12}\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(g'(x)\bigg)^2dx$

i am trying to solve it using Cauchy schwarx integral inequality

$$\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(g(x)g'(x)\bigg)^2dx\leq \int^{1}_{0}(g(x))^2dx\int^{1}_{0}(g'(x))^2dx$$

but did not know how i use $g(0.5)=0$ here and how do i find original inequality prove given in question

help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts gives
$$
 \int_0^{1/2} g(x) \, dx = x g(x) \bigr]_{x=0}^{x=1/2} - \int_0^{1/2} x g'(x) \, dx = - \int_0^{1/2} x g'(x) \, dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{1/2}^1 g(x) \, dx = (x-1) g(x) \bigr]_{x=1/2}^{x=1} - \int_{1/2}^1 (x-1)g'(x) \, dx = \int_{1/2}^1 (1-x) g'(x) \, dx \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
\left | \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx \right | \le \int_0^{1/2} x |g'(x)| \, dx
 + \int_{1/2}^1 (1-x) |g'(x)| \, dx \\
= \int_0^1 \min(x, 1-x) \,  |g'(x)| \, dx \, .
$$
Now we can apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
\left ( \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx \right )^2
  \le \int_0^1 \bigl(\min(x, 1-x)\bigr)^2 \, dx \cdot \int_0^1 g'(x)^2 \, .
$$
Finally note that
$$
\int_0^1 \bigl(\min(x, 1-x)\bigr)^2 \, dx = 2 \int_0^{1/2} x^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{12} \, .
$$